# sanic.exceptions.RequestTimeout: Request Timeout in Sanic

Tags: python-3.x, sanic

I run sanic application and it raises an exception every several seconds even without any request coming in.

```
sanic.exceptions.RequestTimeout: Request Timeout
```

How to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue comes from the fact that the connection remains alive. Adding following configuration seems to have fixed my issue

```
from sanic.config import Config
Config.KEEP_ALIVE = False
```

Answer (score 2):

I would point you towards [the documentation](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/config.html#what-is-keep-alive-and-what-does-the-keep-alive-timeout-value-do) so that you understand what you are doing and why you are receiving that exception. Just blindly changing `KEEP_ALIVE` to `False` may not be what you want.

> The KEEP_ALIVE config variable is set to True in Sanic by default. If you don’t need this feature in your application, set it to False to cause all client connections to close immediately after a response is sent, regardless of the Keep-Alive header on the request.
>
> The amount of time the server holds the TCP connection open is decided by the server itself. In Sanic, that value is configured using the KEEP_ALIVE_TIMEOUT value. By default, it is set to 5 seconds, this is the same default setting as the Apache HTTP server and is a good balance between allowing enough time for the client to send a new request, and not holding open too many connections at once. Do not exceed 75 seconds unless you know your clients are using a browser which supports TCP connections held open for that long.

Comment: While the documentation is pretty clear, it is still mysterious why we are having this exception. I suppose my clients may not properly close connection when required, but should I care? It is not my error and not something I can fix.

Comment: I still lack the understanding of the KEEP ALIVE functionality : If the client hasn't received a response yet, does the "keep alive" still start ? Or does it start once a response has been sent ? I tried with a process that takes quite some time to be run, and if I set the KEEP_ALIVE parameter to False, I have a "Cancelled" error right away

Comment: @CyrilN. That depends on the version. We are in the processing of trying to simplify the various timeouts so it sort of depends upon the version.

Comment: My current version is 21.12.1